# gRPC Service use models from library

Tags: c#, grpc, grpc-c#

I am working on my first gRPC service. I have everything working. As in, I can call my service from the client and get a response. My question is can my gRPC service use models from another library?

I have several projects in my solution.

gRPC Server 
gRPC Client 
Common DTO Library 
And a Few more

When I define my proto file is it possible to use the classes from the Common DTO Library?

my.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "myNameSpace";

package myPackageName;

// The service definition.
service MyService{
  rpc MyMethodName (DtoFromAnotherLibrary) returns (byte[]);
}
```

Thank you,
Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible because Proto does not know about your C# projects.

You may consider using [code-first gRPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first) though, where you write C# code that is then creating your proto.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know all gRPC tricks and started using it relatively recently.

Comment: I would like to add that I used AutoMapper to map in-between the the code first and the dto objects.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ray stated, you cannot use your model objects through the gRPC interface and he provided a link to the code-first method.

I tend to think of my proto definitions as my external interface and update them with care to ensure backwards compatibility as the interface ages.  Because of that, I will code up model objects separate from the gRPC definitions and write extension methods (`ToProto` for the model, `ToModel` for the gRPC message) to go back and forth between the two types.  It may seem like duplicated effort, but having the flexibility to add things to my model objects like property change notifications, or other convenience methods/properties without affecting the external interface is a plus to me.  I spend a lot of time working on the front end, so it analogous to the model/view model relationship.